# Ant build class files with TestNG using textiles

Tags: java, testing, ant

I am using Ant to build my project and am encountering a problem dealing with running my tests with text files when I use TestNG. Below is my code that contains two targets that compile and run my test code:

```
 <target name="compile-tests" depends="compile"
          description="Compile the project test source-code." >

    <mkdir dir="${testBuildDir}" />

    <javac destdir="${testBuildDir}" classpathref="test.path"
           debug="${java.debug}" optimize="${java.opt}" deprecation="on">
      <src path="${testSrcDir}" />
    </javac>

    <!-- Copies text testing files over -->
    <copy todir="${testBuildDir}">
        <fileset dir="${testSrcDir}">
            <include name="**/*.txt" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target>

  <target name="test" depends="compile-tests"
    description="Runs all the unit tests">
    <testng suitename="boggle-tests" outputdir="${testResultsDir}">
        <classpath>
          <path refid="test.path" />
          <pathelement path="${testBuildDir}" />
        </classpath>
        <classfileset dir="${testBuildDir}" />
    </testng>
  </target>
```

Also, I have provided below a list of properties used in my xml file:

```
  <property name="srcDir"  location="src" />
  <property name="libDir"  location="lib" />

  <property name="buildDir" location="build"/>
  <property name="buildClassesDir" location="${buildDir}/classes"/>
  <property name="javaDocDir" location="${buildDir}/javadoc"/>

  <property name="testSrcDir" location="test"/>
  <property name="testBuildDir" location="${buildDir}/tests"/>
  <property name="testResultsDir" location="${buildDir}/results"/>

  <property name="testNGFile" location="${libDir}/testng-6.8.jar" />
```

So I have contained my testing source code and my testing text files used by the source code in the `${testBuildDir}`. My compile-tests target simply compiles the .java files and creates .class files in the destination as well as copying my testing .txt files.

Then my test target just runs all these .class files using the TestNG framework. The problem I am having is that when I run the test target, my test code fails because it says that it could not find the .txt files used for testing purposes. However, I don't understand why this happens since my compile-tests target clearly works as expected and includes the .txt test files.

I have been struggling on this for too long and really need so help.

Comment: Just a wild guess, is the path to the text files in tests hardcoded? When copying txt files to the build dir, they are places under /tests directory, which can be the cause

Comment: For the tests, I barcoded the file name into the program like File f = new File("testingFile.txt"). But since both the testing class files and the test text files are in the same folder, I was thinking that it should work with no problems. I am stuck on dealing with this.

Comment: @buxter I don't understand what you mean. I put both the class files and copied test files in ${testBuildDir}.

Comment: If you write File file = new File ("testFile.txt");
Then you should have the following hierarchy
-->outDir
-->scrDir
-->testFile.txt
They need to be next to the compile folder, not inside

Comment: @buxter The way I organized my test code structure is like this. The source test code and txt testing files go into the {testSrcDir}. The testing code class files and the txt files go into the {testBuildDir}. In order to run the class files, the txt files must be next to it. So I don't understand why the txt files must be outside the class files directory.

Comment: new File("testingFile.txt") is relative to a working directory, which is your root (project) folder.

Comment: So accordingly in my Ant file, I should copy the text files over to ${buildDir} property location and not the ${testBuildDir} property location?

Comment: Just put the txt files under the root project folder, and then you don't need to copy them at all.

Comment: @buxter Thank you so much. I was able to get the testing to work by placing the txt files under the root project folder.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped :)